# How to format thrust::copy(ostream_iterator)

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

### Summary

I am printing device vectors using [this](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/stream_compaction.cu) example. I would like to have the arrays line up.

Format settings are only being applied to the first number.

### My Code

```cpp
template <typename Iterator>
    void print_range(const std::string& name, Iterator first, Iterator last)
    {
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type T;

        std::cout << name << ": ";
        thrust::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::setfill(' '), " "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
```

**The important line is:**

```cpp
thrust::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator < T > (std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::setfill(' '), " "));
```

Current Output

```
Box Numbers :: _110 109 108 109 108 107 106 105 106 105 
Difference  :: _110 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 
Difference 2:: _110 -111 0 2 -2 0 0 0 2 -2 
Key Vector  :: _110 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 
Inclusive   :: _110 -1 -2 1 -1 -2 -3 -4 1 -1
```

Desired Output

```
Box Numbers :: _110  109  108  109  108  107  106 
Difference  :: _110   -1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1   
Difference 2:: _110 -111    0    2   -2    0    0   
Key Vector  :: _110   -1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1  
Inclusive   :: _110   -1   -2    1   -1   -2   -3
```

Format settings are only being applied to the first number. If I change width or fill, its applied to the first number but not the rest of them.

**Note**

- I used the " _ " character only so I can see where the formatting is being applies.
- Outputs are in code blocks because otherwise stack overflow was overriding my formatting and removing sequential spaces.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with CUDA or thrust.  If you search on how to do it e.g. with `std::copy` you'll come across articles like [this](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2008/04/10/output-formatting-with-stdcopy/) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18291/setting-output-width-with-ostream-iterator).

Comment: when I set up an equivalent example with `std::copy` it behaves exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to format the output of thrust::copy to cout. Ended up copying to a host vector. Then I can iterate through the host vector and format that output.

Not too elegant, but gets the job done for this purpose.

```cpp
    template <typename Iterator>
    void print_range(const std::string& name, Iterator first, Iterator last)
    {
        // Print Vector Name
            std::cout << name << ": ";

        // Copy Vector to host
            int print_length = thrust::distance(first, last);
            thrust::host_vector<int> to_print(print_length);
            thrust::copy(first, last, to_print.begin());

         // Print Vector
            for (auto val : to_print)
                std::cout << setw(4) << val;

        std::cout << endl;
    }
```

#### Edit

I found another option that works as well. [Example](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__modifying_ga14cba62489aee67ffa6348eb74997b57.html#ga14cba62489aee67ffa6348eb74997b57)

Use for_each to call a custom printf

```cpp
//----------------------------
//      Print Functor
//----------------------------
    struct printf_functor
    {
        __host__ __device__
        void operator() (int x)
        {
            printf("%4d ", x);
        }
    };

//----------------------------
//      Print Range
//----------------------------
    template <typename Iterator>
    void print_range(const std::string& name, Iterator first, Iterator last)
    {
        // Print Vector Name
            std::cout << name << ": ";

        // Print Each Element
            thrust::for_each(thrust::device, first, last, printf_functor());

        std::cout << endl;
    }
```